# Finding the delay in the stereo output in a recorded audio file

Tags: java, perl, audio, core-audio, perl-module

I am new in the Audio domain.I am recording a file(".wav") from my Java program .I need to measure the time delay between 2 channels in the audio signal.
i.e if channel 1 in '.wav' file starts at x time and channel 2 starts in y time.I need to find by how much time is the channel 2 or 1 is lagging

Comment: What is the code you're already having ?

Comment: From a mathematical point of view, this can be solved quite simple: 1. You combine the two channels using a convolution operation (e.g. using FFT and multiplication). 2. You look for the peak in the convolution, by fitting a model to it (e.g. a quadratic function, fitting with the least-square-sum method), then calculating the peak using analytic methods (e.g. derivation and looking for zeroes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross correlation between two data vectors (channels) is one DSP method of determining lag or delay between the two vectors.